# How to pass argument to file used in nginx command?

Tags: command-line, nginx, arguments

I have the following line in my `nginx.conf` file:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==";
```

Currently, the command to start the nginx is:

```
exec nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Is there any way to pass the string `"Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="` as argument to the command above, and use the value inside the `nginx.conf` file?

I mean if something like this is possible:

```
exec nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this code: [with help from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590244/how-to-properly-encode-string-based-on-json-file)

```
#!/bin/sh

json_file=nginx/auth/basic.json
auth_header=$(jq '"Basic " + ("\(.user):\(.pass)" | @base64)' $json_file)

basicAuth=$(cat << EOF
map "" \$basicAuth {\n\tdefault $auth_header;\n}
EOF
)

conf_file=nginx/auth/basic.conf
echo $basicAuth > $conf_file
```

That converts this json:

```
{
    "user": "user",
    "pass": "password"
}
```

Into this conf file:

```
map "" $basicAuth {
    default "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==";
}
```

---

Then I was able to import that `basic.conf` file in my `nginx.conf` file:

```
http {
    include auth/auth.conf;
    ...
```

And use in my specific locations:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization $basicAuth;
```

Nginx is now proxying requests with the properly authentications.