# How to properly encode string based on json file?

Tags: command-line, string, jq, base64

I have the following `basic.json` file:

```
{
    "user": "user",
    "pass": "password"
}
```

I'm trying to encode it in base64 like this:

```
"Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="
```

I think I'm close:

```
echo Basic $(echo $(cat basic.json | jq '.user'):$(cat basic.json | jq '.pass') | base64)
```

I've used the [jq access method found here](https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/#how-to-find-a-key-and-value).

I've used the [base64 method found here](https://linuxhint.com/bash_base64_encode_decode/).

But the result is wrong:

```
Basic InVzZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCIK
```

I've tried the `-e` flag as mentioned in the article:

```
echo Basic $(echo $(cat basic.json | jq '.user'):$(cat basic.json | jq '.pass') | base64 -e)
```

But it throws this error:

> base64: invalid option -- 'e'

Where did I mistake?

Thanks in advance.

---

**My solution**

The command ended this way:

```
RUN echo "map \"\" \$basicAuth {\n\
\tdefault $(jq '"Basic " + ("\(.user):\(.pass)" | @base64)' basic.json);\n\
}" > basic.conf
```

And my `basic.conf` file finally have the correct basic auth:

```
map "" $basicAuth {
    default "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==";
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to encode? the whole *file* - or individual fields such as `pass`? If the latter, then `jq` has a `@base64` that will do so directly, at least in recent versions

Comment: The file is just the input, the string `"Basic <base64>"` is my desired output. I will search `@base64` in jq docs, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jq` and `@base64` operator:

```
<basic.json jq '"Basic " + ("\(.user):\(.pass)"|@base64)'
"Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="
```

`user` and `pass` values are given as string to `base64` operator. The rest is simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

`jq` provides a number of output format filters, including a `@base64`.

So for example if you want to encode the whole JSON object in file `basic.json`, then you could use something like

```
$ jq -r '. | @base64 | "Basic \(.)"' basic.json
Basic eyJ1c2VyIjoidXNlciIsInBhc3MiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9
```

The `"Basic \(.)"` filter just uses string interpolation to get your desired format.

---

A more conventional use of such a filter might be to encode particular values ex.

```
$ jq '.pass |= @base64' basic.json
{
  "user": "user",
  "pass": "cGFzc3dvcmQ="
}
```